# NBody Simulation - appropriate design approach

Tags: database, cuda, opencl, cpu, gpu

I have a problem where I am going to have a bunch of nbodies - the movements of each is predescribed by existing data, however when a body is in the range of another one certain properties about it change. For the sake of this question we'll just assume you have a counter per body that counts the time you were around other bodies. So basically you start with t = 0, you spend 5 seconds around body 2, so your t is now 5. I am wondering what's the best way I should go about this, I don't have the data yet, but I was just wondering if it's appropriate for me to explore something like CUDA/OpenCL or should I stick with optimizing this across a multi-core cpu machine. Because the amount of data that this will be simulated across is about 500 bodies, which each have movements described down to the second over a 30 day period, so that's 43200 points of data per body.

Comment: You can find NBody projects in the NVIDIA and AMD SDKs. And here the Intel sample: http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/samples/opencl-cross-devices-nbody-simulation-sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brute force nbody is definitely suited to GPUs, because it is "embarrassingly parallel".  Each body-to-body interaction computation is completely independent of any other.  Your variation that includes keeping track of time spent in the "presence" of other bodies would be a straightforward addition to the existing body-to-body force computation, since everything is done on a timestep basis anyway.

[Here's some sample CUDA code for nbody](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-n-body-simulation).